# Deleting photos using API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photos

Currently the API to delete photos do not seem to work.

Are others facing this issue?

Comment: maybe it's a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/125524667559003?browse=search_4f658e84d8d740f16069620)?